# Why I cannot call the base class Constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

I have a class that is a child of `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. I am trying to call its constructor but I have a problem during the call of the base class constructor.

More specifically I want to call that particular constructor:

> `Bitmap(String)`: Initializes a new instance of the Bitmap class from the specified file.

I think the problem is that it does not recognize that my class inherits from the `Bitmap` class, because the **error refers to the Object class**.

In any case, here is my class:

```
class MyBitmap : Bitmap
{
    private String photographer, description, title;
    public String Photographer
    {
        get
        {
            return this.photographer;
        }
    }
    public String Description
    {
        get
        {
            return this.description;
        }
    }

    public String Title
    {
        get
        {
            return this.title;
        }
    }

    public MyBitmap(String filePath, String title, String description, String photographer) : base(filePath)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.photographer = photographer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for your error is that [`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,e1ba6ce9c451889d) is a *sealed* class.

So you are **not allowed** to inherit from `Bitmap` at all. Check your compiler error messages, you should have received an error [`CS0509`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0509).

Comment: Well to be honest I didn't knew anything about sealed classes, but I have never received an error CS0509. Thanks!